GA4: UTM Codes Not Appearing
Programmatic advertiser here.
Many of our clients are experiencing issues where they're not seeing UTM data populate in their GA4 dashboards in either real-time or custom reporting. We are running ads in various DSPs, so checking in with the Google Ads manual tagging settings shouldn't be an issue here. Beyond that, when I manually navigate to a client's website with a UTM on the URL, it does not appear in reporting.
For one client, we typically deliver several hundred clicks per day, but I am seeing just under 20 sessions on that specific UTM for the last 30 days. So they ARE registering, just not 1:1 (or even close, really).
So far, I've checked Analytics configurations in all of their Tag Managers and all checks out there (unless there's some GA4 specific GTM setups I need to do to enable UTM collection).
Any ideas on what to check next?
So far, I've checked Analytics configurations in all of their Tag Managers and all checks out there (unless there's some GA4 specific GTM setups I need to do to enable UTM collection). I've also looked into redirects. That's not my strongest area and I do see some 302 statuses, but to my knowledge, that shouldn't affect things.

Looks to me like you've skipped the first debugging step.
Inspect your network requests, see where the utms are set and where they aren't set and compare those hits to the hits you're looking at in GA. Only after that do you really want to start paying attention to redirects or GTM configs.
That's really it. Not much debugging can be done before you actually locate the cause. I would also suggest looking at the BQ data since it will show hit-level urls with query params without sampling, so it makes it way easier to debug issues like these.
